# Generating random strings with few characters

Tags: python, string, random

I'd like to generate unique random strings with Python, so I'm leveraging [uuid4](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4).

```
from uuid import uuid4

def generate_random_string():
    return uuid4().hex
```

The problem is that it generates strings with too many characters. One possible solution that I came up with is to convert the string from base 16 to base 62 (digits + lowercase/uppercase letters). It works, but the result still has too many characters (22 to be more precise). Something between 6 and 10 chars would be great, but I'm afraid they might not be unique some time in the future. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: That's an option, but it has a higher risk to be duplicated is the future.

Comment: No higher than any other 10-character string. If you want less chance of collision, you need more characters.  That's just a fact of nature.

Comment: And the chance of collision between two 10-character case-sensitive alnum strings is less than winning the lottery (jackpot) twice in a row. Just for scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives control over the length of the generated string, however, as @Keven mentioned in the comments, if you want less chance of collision in the future, you need to use more characters. Though it seems quite unlikely.

```
from random import sample
from string import digits, ascii_letters 

chars = digits + ascii_letters
#'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

gen_str = sample(chars, 10)
```

**example output:**

```
['2', '8', 'G', 'o', 'U', 'e', 'K', 'f', 'w', '7']

>>> ''.join(gen_str)

'28GoUeKfw7'
```

**info on [random module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)**